# The color does not show correct in the design view of android studio

Tags: android-studio

[The background color in design view of android studio is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Kos.png)

[This is my color.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ouy.png)

[The color of the button "=" is Orange and I do not set any color to the rest of buttons, but all button show purple in Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tq7w.png)

Comment: The description is not very detailed and is not in line with what the community expects from how a question should be written. Please delete your questions and re-think about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the theme? You can make your own theme (just a suggestion).

Or use `AppCompatButton`, example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

    android:id="@+id/yourButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:text="Your text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="20dp"
    app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: what is the theme? you mean the IDE theme or something else? I am new to android studio and just learn it. The IDE theme is default and I did not change anything

Comment: try AppCompatButton